# datetime parameters in reporting service

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, format

I need to specify time in datetime parameters in reporting services. I have two parameters as startdate and enddate, when user selects the startdate and enddate. The reporting services automatically specifies time as 12:00:00 and I want to change to have some default time instead 12:00:00 and Also, I am calling a stored procedure with parameters.

Comment: When the user selects the startdate and enddate, the reporting service add the time stamp as 12:00:00 as the time but i want to change that to some other time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameters are passed to a Stored Procedure then, update the value to add a default time before using it in the query.

You can do it in two ways

```
 `SET @StartDate = @StartDate + '6:00:00.00'` -- Adds 6 Hours or


 SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Hour,6,@StartDate)
 SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Minute,30,@StartDate)
 SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Second,45,@StartDate)
```

The above add 06:30:45 to the @StartDate parameter.

You can do the same with the @EndDate parameter.

Comment: I get this error message 'Value is not a date or time'

Comment: Do you get this during report execution or in the Query? Are the parameters in the Stored Procedure declared as DateTime?

Comment: yes they are declared but i used the above statements in default in StartDate parameters before the query execution

Comment: These should be set in the Stored procedure not as defaults in the report itself. Let the user choose the date and you make the changes to the them in the Stored Procedure.